# install `pysal` but get error report: `ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ygsexy4a`

Tags: pip, pysal

Trying to install `pysal`, (Python Spatial Analysis Library), but get the error report. I have searched and read lots of answers, most of the solutions are upgrade `setuptools`. But I have tried and nothing changed. I tried to reinstall `pandas` with pip, everything goes well without any error report. By the way, I have also tried to install the old version of `setuptools` and `pip`, the error still occurred.

Can anyone help me solve this error? Thanks for your help.

```py
C:\Users\kenny>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/simple
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\users\kenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (63.2.0)

C:\Users\kenny>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\users\kenny\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (22.2.1)

C:\Users\kenny>pip install pysal
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/simple
Collecting pysal
  Using cached https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/e0/da/6d67ab14112985dd0d530c058fd1004a3b8ba8514f6166c7903104c65f2e/pysal-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting spopt>=0.2.1
  Using cached https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/a6/e4/24e4efa4798372a04ece786bc4983c7617cc0fece1e4f6e980d723bee63b/spopt-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting access>=1.1.3
  Downloading https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/06/34/3fa0407af9ac1c27784d816629480e3ea11f5ba6317a1bb04ebb6097e134/access-1.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting inequality>=1.0.0
  Using cached https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/74/0f/9ed2d097f29160d0c873f33ffc0b9806c1083e3611acb2143eb66adcf580/inequality-1.0.0.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ygsexy4a
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about this question. Just provide another solution to install pysal. I installed this package from [git](https://github.com/pysal/pysal) directly and successful. just  `git clone https://github.com/pysal/pysal` - `cd pysal` - `python setup.py install`. I hope this can help you. End